# Sql Server 2012 Full Text Search - Slow response on initial queries

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

I've a website running an eCommerce shop based on Sql Server 2012 Web Edition. The database is more and less 4GB and it contains 20.000 items circa. 
This database is configured as "Simple" and contains a full text catalog whose size is 15MB.

Whenever I start up the site and try to search, the store procedure that uses the FTS runs out of time after 30 secs. This behavior continues for the following 2-3 searches. After that, everything goes smoothly and results are retrieved.

I've tried to scale up the server on which the website is hosted, but nothing changed. I've also tried to host the site database on a dedicated machine but no improvement noticed. I tried to configure a population schedule for the full text catalog, but nothing seems changed.

I really cannot understand what could that be because when I search:

1. website is obviously started and so the process is running and AppPool is configured
2. database should be turned on, as on the first page there are some products that taken (if they are not in cache) from the db. I suppose that caching is not so used because the same server is used by more and less 10 other eCommerce websites.
3. after 1-5 queries everything goes smoothly for a period of time

Anyone has some ideas?

Here is an extract from the code.

1. website launches a search by invoking a stored procedure.
2. Stored procedure takes 15 parameters. One of these is Keyword that is the searched text
3. This is what the stored procedure does at the true beginning if Keyword is not null and if there is a full text catalog on the DB:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #ProductFullTextSearch ([ProductID] int NOT NULL)  
   SET @Keywords = isnull(@Keywords, '""')
   IF(@Keywords = '') SET @Keywords = '""'
   IF (@Keywords <> '""')
   BEGIN
   IF(@SearchExact = 1) 
   SET @Keywords = '"*' + @Keywords +'*"'
   ELSE 
   SET @Keywords = '"*' + REPLACE(@Keywords, ' ', '*" AND "*') +'*"'
   PRINT @Keywords

   INSERT INTO #ProductFullTextSearch(ProductID)
   SELECT p.ProductID
   FROM Nop_Product p with (NOLOCK) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Nop_ProductVariant pv with (NOLOCK) ON p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
   WHERE 
   p.Deleted = 0 AND ((CONTAINS((p.name), @Keywords))
   or (@SearchDescriptions = 1 and CONTAINS((p.ShortDescription, p.FullDescription), @Keywords))
   )

   INSERT INTO #ProductFullTextSearch(ProductID)
   SELECT p.ProductID
   FROM Nop_Product p with (NOLOCK) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Nop_ProductVariant pv with (NOLOCK) ON p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
   WHERE 
   p.Deleted = 0 AND ((CONTAINS((pv.name, pv.SKU), @Keywords))
   or (@SearchDescriptions = 1 and CONTAINS(pv.Description, @Keywords))
   )
   END
   ```
4. That part creates a temp table which is used to insert ProductIds that respond to the query text.
5. Stored Procedure filters products using other parameters and removing items whose ID are not contained in the temp table

Comment: Try posting some code for a query or two so we can see how you are searching.

Comment: check the maximum pool size for the concurrent connections

Comment: Is this your issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915850

Comment: @user814064: I really don't believe that is the issue. I don't run Sql Server 2005 and there is 100% network connection. Do you think that Sql Server 2012 may be afflicted by the same issue too?

Comment: @user1102001: You say on my asp.net application?

Comment: Are there errors in the server event viewer during start-up?

Comment: @user814064: I'd say no errors, but I see a big number of failed attempted connection to the database server. Maybe a DDoS?

Comment: There's a site for database issues: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ though they wouldn't necessarily be able to trouble-shoot without more info about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

the behavior you observe is very likely because of a missing index in one or more tables referenced by the FTS procedure. In case of a missing index, Sql Server will build it's own internal index upon the first call to the relevant stored procedure therefore you get that initial delay. To avoid this delay you need to create the missing index yourself.

Follow these steps:

1. Run SQL Server Profiler and capture the exact stored procedure text with parameters which is run initially by your app.
2. In SQL Server Management Studio connect to your DB, press the Include Actual Execution Plan button and run your query manually.
3. In the Results window switch to the Execution Plan tab and look if you have any missing index reported by server.
4. If there are such missing indexes than copy index description and create it in DB permanently.

Note, I'm talking about missing plain/normal non-clustered table index and not FTS index/catalog.

PS. Sorry for the delayed reply, but I'm having FTS searching performance issues myself so just found your unanswered question. Though my problems are not related to a missing index.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot check because that website is currently dead but I'll keep that in mind! Thanks